# mysql query to return 'NaN' in values which don't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so, with :

```
person_id|attr|value
int      |A-Z |int
```

There are many rows with duplicate person_id, but each person_id uses each of the 26 possible values (A-Z) as attr no more than once. Not all person_id covers the entire range of A-Z.
Example:

```
1|A|0.2
1|B|0.6
2|Z|0.12
```

I would like to search in table like so:

```
select attr, value from table where person_id=1 ...
```

returns:

```
A 0.2
B 0.5
C NaN
.
.
Z 25
```

Notice that always 26 rows will be returned, one for each attribute. Even if no rows match that attribute. In this example, C returns NaN since no rows exist.

Note that for simplicity I use attributes A-Z, but actually I would like to get all of the unique attributes used in the table:

```
SELECT distinct `attr `FROM `table`
```

Comment: How are you storing decimal values in an int column?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff just a simpified example. I wasn't paying attention to the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing that is generating a full table like this:

```
create table alpha (attr char(1) primary key);
insert into alpha values ('A');
insert into alpha values ('B');
insert into alpha values ('C');
insert into alpha values ('D'); 
[...]
insert into alpha values ('Z');
```

Then:

```
SELECT a.attr, IFNULL(t.value,'NaN') 
FROM alpha a 
LEFT JOIN test t ON a.attr = t.attr AND t.person_id = 1 
ORDER BY a.attr;
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05a76/6/0